# Why width of Slider within Row is shrinked?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
Column(                                         // w=375; 0 <= w<= 375
  children: [
    Slider(value: 0.33, onChanged: (v) {}),     // w=375; 0 <= w<= 375
    Row(                                        // w=375; 0 <= w<= 375
      // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,        // nothing changed
      children: [
        Slider(value: 0.33, onChanged: (v) {}), // w=192; width is unconstrained
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

Here are two Slider, one is within Row and one is not.

I excpacted that both Row has same(max) size of width, but the Slider within Row is shrinked.

Why does it and how can I make it take all of parent(Row)'s width?

- `mainAxisSize` parameter does not cause influence.
- In dev tool, Sliders Row is `w=192; width is unconstrained`.
- When I replace Row to Column, Slider takes max width.

Here is [Full code in dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/46e90db5657d0c83748ac13b4967c1c4?null_safety=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very simple way if you embed the widget in a row it will only take space which it requires that is intrinsic. If you want it to take available space. Wrap it with Expanded and your work is done.

```
   Row(
               
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                    child:Slider(value: 0.33, onChanged: (v) {})
                    ),
                  ],
```